# Can't connect to a SQL Server database using a specific network

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-connection

I'm working from a new place and I'm unable to connect to a remote database using the wi-fi, but it works if I route my mobile 4g as a hotspot.

I've contacted the internet provider and they say there's nothing blocking the access. And it seems true because it allows me to connect to the VPN and I can access the remote desktop where the database is hosted and in there I'm able to connect to the database using SSMS without any errors, but when I try to connect directly from my PC I get the following error.
[image]

Any idea what could be causing this or how can I investigate where the problem is?

- I'm using SSMS v18.9.1, windows authentication and connecting using the server name like "srv123.xxxx.com\instprd". This configuration works when I use the 4g hotspot instead of the wi-fi.

Comment: The port could be blocked for you wi-fi connection.

Comment: I checked the port using Telnet and didn't get any errors.

Comment: The named instance connection uses UDP port 1434 to determine the port number of the named instance. Perhaps UDP is blocked on the WiFi.

Comment: Could you tell me how to check if that's the case?

Comment: Maybe this can help : [Troubleshoot connectivity issues in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/connect/resolve-connectivity-errors-overview).

Answer (score 0):

Tried what I could and then I talked to the ISP support and it was indeed that some ports were blocked.
Some update on the router (tp link AC1200) firmware caused it so they had to downgrade it and that solved the problem.